# WebViev message notifications

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native WebView application. My members in it are messaging each other. I want a notification to be sent when one of my users sends a message to another. How can I achieve this. Are there any pages you can recommend? Please, I would appreciate it if you could help. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share some of your existing code base? That would make it easier to suggest what to add/use. :)

Comment: I currently have a normal WebView application. I haven't added anything yet. I will add it if it can be done. I want to send notifications in users' messaging. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, it can be done - the native apps for AriBnB and Instagram are built with React Native.  Are you using a database, or will your messages disappear when your local server restarts?

Comment: I have a Wordpress website. I use MYSQL and phpmyadmin as the database. I made the WebView application.